# jdbc microsoft SQLServerDriver datasource thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, sql-server-2005, jdbc

I wanted to check if the jdbc code that I am using to get connection is thread-safe:

**Environment:**

```
Database - MS SQL Server 2005 Express Edition

Driver Class Name - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

JDBC Jar: sqljdbc4.jar (downloaded from Microsoft website)

Application Server - Apache Tomcat 7.0
```

Here are the parameters under the resource element in context.xml file:

```
name="jdbc/xyzResourceName" 

auth="Container" 

type="javax.sql.DataSource" 

username="someUserName" 

password="somePassword" 

driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 

url="jdbc:sqlserver://someHost;instanceName=someInstance;schema=someSchema;DatabaseName=someDB;" 

maxActive="8" 

maxIdle="4"
```

I am using a singleton named HMDataService and using its static methods to do some CRUD operations. Here is the HMDataService class:

public class HMDataService {

```
private static HMDataService instance = null;
private static **DataSource ds** = null;    

protected HMDataService() {
    // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
}

public static HMDataService getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {         
        instance = new HMDataService();
        Context ctx;
        try {
                            // Context lookup hardcoded only for simplicity
            ctx = new InitialContext();
            ctx = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");
            **ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/xyzResourceName");**                       
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            log.error("Some Problem To Log", e);
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

public static void someInsertOperation(String insertRecord) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    try {
        **connection = ds.getConnection();**            
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("Some SQL Here");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, insertRecord);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();  
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Some Error Here", e);            
    } finally {     
        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            preparedStatement.close();
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }       
}
```

}

This HMDataService and its method someInsertOperation will be called randomly by any number of threads from either a servlet or a jsp.
The sample code to call it is as follows:

```
HMDataService.getInstance().someInsertOperation("Some Record To Insert");
```

I want to know if this is thread safe or not ? I've checked online for SQLServerDriver documentation on Microsoft website, but I couldn't get any information whether the datasource.getConnection() is thread safe or not. I know that the thread safety is specific to the particular JDBC driver implementation. But, I don't know if it is for this particular implementation of JDBC driver for MS SQL Server.

Comment: This is a total cop-out of an answer (hence I'm writing it as just a comment), but in my experience, if the library doesn't proudly advertise/boast that its thread-safe, it's probably not. Writing thread safe code is not necessarily the easiest thing in the world, and so when a library does manage to pull it off, it usually markets that fact *everywhere*. Just FWIW!